Entering the US from China for the first time with an Indian passport
I have a newly issued 10-year US B1/B2 visa on my Indian passport. I will have to be in Shanghai for a week before flying to the US for the 1st time using this visa. Does anyone here have any experience of flying out of China to the US using a US visa whilst being a non-Chinese citizen/resident? My US visa was issued in the UK where I live. I am curious to know if, due to flying out of Shanghai, I will have to take some extra steps as opposed to flying out of the country I am resident in (and the country where the visa was issued).

I'm sorry but your question doesn't make any sense. That you're visiting China before travelling to the USA is inconsequential. Sure the US CBP may ask you about the trip if they feel the need to but other than that, what country you fly from or transit from is irrelevant.

Why do you think this would be a problem?  Suppose you were going to China, Japan. Canada, the US, Mexico, Brazil and Argentina.  Would you have to fly from one country to the next by way of the UK to avoid "extra steps"?  Of course not.

Why the downvotes?? This question is on-topic and seems to be asked in good faith. Some people may think it's a stupid question, but it may not be obvious to everyone.  Besides, it's normal to worry about all sorts of details before a major thing like international travel.

@Aqualone No-one has said this is a stupid question, rather that it is unclear what the actual problem is.  The tooltip for the down-vote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - I feel this question fits well within the "it is unclear" part, and this is probably the reason for the down-votes.  If the asker wishes to clarify the problem those down-votes could turn to up-votes.

Apart from the reason for your concern being unclear, the likelihood of anyone who has a US 10 year visa issued in the UK to an Indian citizen who is travelling to US from China is probably infinitesimally small. Unless someone exactly matches your circumstances, any personal experience that might be shared would be meaningless.

No, you should have nothing to worry about here. Your US visa, once issued, may be used to enter the US from any country. You may face an extra question or two at immigration, especially if the itinerary you are taking differs substantially from the one you provided on the visa application, but answer honestly and concisely, and you should be fine.
